# EF Code First DbMigrator takes long time to instantiate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We run migrations from within our application to create databases on the fly. We also use migrations in our unit/integration tests to create databases for the tests to use. A few months ago we noticed the run-time of our tests substantially increased and we've been able to narrow it down to the instantiation of the `DbMigrator` class. Even with a very simple `Configuration` class it still takes ~10 seconds to create the `DbMigrator`.

For example, here's the Configuration class taken from the "Elastic DB Tools - Entity Framework" sample application.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ElasticScaleContext<int>>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        this.ContextKey = "CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample.BloggingContext";
    }
}
```

Here is the code used to create and run the migrations.

```
var configurator = new Configuration();
configurator.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connStrBldr.ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configurator);
migrator.Update();
```

And here's the trace information from VS2015.

[image]

1. Time to instantiate `Configuration`
2. Time to set the `TargetDatabase` property
3. Time to instantiate `DbMigrator`

We're using Entity Framework 6.1.3. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I am getting this as well. Getting almost 20 seconds on web app start

Comment: @mirhagk, a couple of months back I downloaded the EF source code so I could debug through it. What I discovered was that the way EF attempts to determine if the database exists is to try to connect to it. If the connection attempt times out it assumes it doesn't exist and creates it. However, that time-out takes time. We modified our code to check if the database exists using a different (i.e. much faster) approach and then we create the database using embedded SQL if it doesn't exist. That massively sped things up. Not sure why the EF team decided on that approach.

Comment: @CraigW. Thanks for this info, but how does this solve the speed issue with instantiation of the DbMigrator? It still needs to be instantiated with a target database, or how did you work around this?

Comment: @Gary, unfortunately we've rewritten that code a couple of times since I posted my last comment in 2016. I don't recall the technique we used to check if the database exists, but as the comment mentioned we still use embedded SQL to create the database then instantiate the DbMigrator. That way when the underlying code checks for existence it finds the database very quickly (because the connection doesn't have to time out) and moves on.

Comment: @CraigW. Ok, so I guess this really only helps when the database does not exist. Got it. Instantiation on an existing database only takes around half a second, but was seeing if there was room to improve on that. Thanks!